# Finding the uniformly most powerful invariant test

Tags: group-theory, probability-theory, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing, invariance

As a "bonus" question (i.e. volontary), I got a question regarding invariance in my inference class I'm taking. So I'm trying to understand invariance, and uniformly most powerful invariant tests (UMPI tests). In terms of hypothesis testing, I have understood that invariance means that one-to-one transformations does not affect the decision (reject/not reject null hypothesis) we make.  The question is:

Let X<sub>1</sub> ,...., X<sub>n</sub> be i.i.d N($\mu$, $\sigma$). Consider the problem of testing H<sub>0</sub> : $\mu$ = 0 vs H<sub>1</sub> : $\mu$ $\ne$ 0, and the group of transformations defined by g<sub>c</sub>(X<sub>i</sub>) = cX<sub>i</sub>, c $\ne$ 0. Show that the testing problem is invariant with respect to the mentioned group. Derive a UMPI test.

Hope that there is someone here with more understanding of these types of problems, I'm really interested in understanding this but the only book I found that deals with this, I'm having a hard time understanding (Mathematical statistics, by Shao).